# Best practice: Maven project with JAX-WS client against mostly offline WSDL

Tags: java, maven, wsimport

I have a Maven project which needs to access a web service under my control, but which is mostly unavailable during development.

I would like Maven to be fully aware of this, including generate classes with wsimport as needed.   The classes may go in source control to avoid having to regenerate after a fresh checkout, but should be easily updateable if needed.

The service is based on Metro - the JAX-WS implementation present in Java 6+ - I have just written the classes, annotated them properly and exposed them with Endpoint.publish.  Metro can then generate the WSDL on demand, by referring to "http://foo.bar/ws?wsdl".  That WSDL for some reason uses a `<xsd:import ...` to get additional information, so it cannot just be copied as-is to the file system.

I understand that there exists a jaxws:wsimport plugin, but I am not familiar enough with the process yet to be certain the above is fulfilled.

How should I approach this?